# Unable to change colour theme in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse

After installing the available updates I am no longer able to change the colour theme for new workspaces. Right now all text based files are essentially unreadable:

[image]

I have no error messages in the log. The build reported right now is the following:

Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

How can I change the theme to something readable?

Comment: under Preferences, look out for Text Editors (General > Editors > Text Editors) and check unter "Appearance color options" that "System default" is NOT checked on foreground and background. I had this problem, too and was able to fix it this way.

Comment: did U tried color theme plugin ???

Comment: Hi mondjunge, I had in fact the "System default" options checked, but even if they are unchecked, when a apply a colour theme (say "Oblivion"), I still get the dark foreground.

Comment: Looks like  some alien attacked your workspace.  Try switching to new workspace..

Comment: This problem happens on ***every*** new workspace.